# Eclipse shutdown after start error due to wrong username or password

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I am getting error **Wrong username or password** when I try to start Eclipse. I checked logs and found this exception. I am unable to understand.

```
!SESSION 2012-06-25 16:57:53.716 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20110909-1335
java.version=1.7.0_03
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish 4 1 2012-06-25 16:58:16.428
!MESSAGE GlassFish: error 
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 502 for URL: http://localhost:9249/__asadmin/__locations
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.enterprise.jst.server.sunappsrv.commands.CommandRunner.handleReceive(CommandRunner.java:755)
    at com.sun.enterprise.jst.server.sunappsrv.commands.CommandRunner.call(CommandRunner.java:639)
    at com.sun.enterprise.jst.server.sunappsrv.commands.CommandRunner.call(CommandRunner.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 502 for URL: http://localhost:9249/__asadmin/__locations
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.enterprise.jst.server.sunappsrv.commands.CommandRunner.call(CommandRunner.java:611)
    ... 6 more

!ENTRY oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish 4 150 2012-06-25 16:58:16.428
!MESSAGE Wrong user name or password.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me suggest you a very simple solution for this.uninstall `Glassfish` from your eclipse and reinstall.Now While installation , when glassfish installer ask you for password for `username:admin` then put a password or just put "admin" as a password.I  want you ti not empty the password field.
Now when you will run the server ,it will ask you for the username and apssword and you should giver there that username and password
It worked for me when I got this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a Glassfish plugin for Eclipse. It is trying to connect to the server's admin port, but the configuration is wrong. The message "Wrong username or password" is what the plugin code has deduced from the server returning HTTP error 502, but that error is not associated with a bad username/password, at least not obviously.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that eclipse plugin. The plugin is malfunctioning because it should not close Eclipse just because it failed to initialize. Due to that you are now unable to start Eclipse and reconfigure. Did you try googling for something like "eclipse glassfish http 502"?

Comment: Ha ha, I just did and the first hit is this very post! Boy, is that Google fast :)